# Error parsing date histogram filter in Kibana visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm using Kibana version 4.4.1 with ES 2.2.0 from the Debian repos.

I have a field with the following type defined:

```
        "InvitationTime" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
        }
```

I created a data table visualization with a date histogram aggregation on this field:

[image: Data table]

When I click on one of the dates to filter though, I get an error where it tries to parse the millis-since-epoch value of the field in my field format:

[image: Filter parse error]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks
Wong

Comment: What happens if you modify your mapping with the following format instead: `"format" : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z||epoch_millis"`. You probably need to recreate your index and re-index your data.

Comment: Amazing. This worked. I'm not too sure about how it worked though so if you can explain it would be great. In any case, can you post this solution as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your mapping with the following format instead:

```
"format" : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z||epoch_millis"
```

You also need to recreate your index and re-index your data. It should work fine.